# How can I return the name and value of a drop down in Java Web?

Tags: java, servlets, web, netbeans

I have an HTML page named Order that includes a drop-down:

```
<select name="Pizzas">
    <option value="15.80" name="Napoletana">Napoletana</option>
    <option value="16.95" name="Margherita">Margherita</option>
    <option value="17.50" name="Sardiniana">Sardiniana</option>
    <option value="16.85" name="Pollo Dolce">Pollo Dolce</option>
    <option value="14.95" name="Funghi">Funghi</option>
    <option value="15.60" name="Patate Con Aglio">Patate Con Aglio</option>
    <option value="15.60" name="Romana">Romana</option>
    <option value="17.85" name="Gamberetti">Gamberetti</option>
    <option value="18.75" name="Capri">Capri</option>
    <option value="14.30" name="La Mexicana">La Mexicana</option>
    <option value="15.60" name="Pomodori Secchi">Pomodori Secchi</option>
    <option value="17.70" name="Proscuitto Con Pomodori">Proscuitto Con Pomodori</option>
    <option value="19.90" name="Siciliana">Siciliana</option>
    <option value="16.70" name="Palermo">Palermo</option>
    <option value="19.05" name="Pesto">Pesto</option>
</select>
```

I want to get the name and value of the option so I can pass it to a Servlet. So far I figured out how to pass the value, which is:

```
String[] pizzas = request.getParameterValues("Pizzas");
```

And then to display it:

```
out.println("<strong>Pizza: </strong>");
if (pizzas != null) {
    for (String pizza: pizzas) {
        out.println("<br/>Price: " + pizza);
    }
}
```

So how would I be able to pass the names also? I'm trying to create a receipt so that I can have: Pizza: "name" and Price: "price"!

Comment: Unfortunately, your values are not unique.  Instead, use unique values for the option (eg, `value="8"` or `value="Capri"`), and look up the price based on that unique id.  `name` is not an attribute of the [`option`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp) tag.

Answer (score 1):

Only the option value is passed to the server.  But with creative use of the option’s value, you can pass multiple pieces of data as the value.

```
<option value="15.80;Napoletana">Napoletana</option>
```

In your server code, split the value at your item separator …

```
String f[] = pizza.split(";");
System.out.println(f[1] + " costs " + f[0]);
```

---

I should point out: storing critical information client side is opening yourself to attacks.  A malicious user can craft their own request string, such that they order the "0.80;Napoletana" pizza, and save $15.

It is better to use unique ids client side, and look up critical information server side.

Answer (score -1):

When you post a form, it sends selected option's value with select element's name not the option element's name attribute.
So you could get Pizzas=selected options value. For example Pizzas : 15.60

You can try to send custom json instead.

```
var formData = {};
formData.pizzaName = $('#Pizzas').find(":selected").attr("name");
formData.pizzaValue = $('#Pizzas').find(":selected").val(); 
// You may add more data from your form here

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'Test',
    data: JSON.stringify(formData),
    success: function(data) { console.log("Success"); },
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I decided to use split and just store name and price separated by a comma in the value!

Comment: You're welcome. I would too :) It is a quick solution.

Comment: Quick, but oh so flawed!